# angularFireAuth with ui-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, firebase, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use `angularFireAuth` (from AngularFire - Firebase) with `ui-route`.

The problem is that the `angularFireAuth` needs `ng-route` as a dependency, so I will have to include it in my module.

The only way working now is to include the `ng-route` in my module but not to configure it.

Is there any better way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Grab the latest `angularFire.js` from their repo: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/master/angularfire.js

They removed the dependency for ng-route in the latest version

Comment: If you're using bower or other package manager, note that it has not been updated on there yet. You have to manually grab angularFire.js (or the min version) from their repo